# How do you solve $\dot{X} = UX$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $X(t) = \left[\begin{matrix}a(t) & b(t) \\c(t) & d(t)\end{matrix}\right]$ and let $U$ be a nonsingular matrix. How do you solve
$$\frac{d}{dt} X(t)=UX(t)$$
I presume there is some general method to solve these kinds of ODEs but I cannot find anything about it, online.

BTW: -----------------

I know that you can get 4 ODE equations for the four unknown functions of $t$. The problem is that each ODE equation includes other functions as so
$$\frac{d a}{d t}=u_{11}a+u_{12}c$$

Comment: If $U$ is a *constant* matrix (unchanging as a function of $t$), this should be stated.  The solutions are then the standard matrix exponentials.  If $U$ varies with time, then the problem is more complicated and scarcely anything can be said without knowledge of what defines $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

The solution is known to be
$$X(t)=\exp\bigl(U(t)\bigr) X(0),$$
so you have to compute $\exp\bigl(U(t)\bigr)$. This supposes you can  write $U(t)$ as the sum $D(t)+N(t)$, where  $D(t)$ is a diagonal matrix and $N(t)$ a nilpotent matrix, which commute  (*Jordan-Chevalley decomposition*).

Comment: Thanks, I remember now. I think I did something with these in systems theory.

Comment: Of course, it's easier if the coefficients  are  $at, bt$ &c.

Comment: I don't know if it has really nothing to do, but it's the French naming of this result, for some reason

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is

$$X(t)=e^{Ut}X(0)$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume $U$ is a constant matrix, i.e., does not depend on $t$.

We need some initial conditions.  So suppose

$X(t_0) = \begin{bmatrix} a(t_0) & b(t_0) \\ c(t_0) & d(t_0) \end{bmatrix}; \tag 1$

then the general solution of

$\dot X = UX \tag 2$

is

$X(t) = e^{(t - t_0) U} X(t_0) = \exp ((t - t_0)U) X(t_0); \tag 3$

we may validate (2) *via* direct differentiation, using the fact that

$\dfrac{d \exp((t - t_0)U)}{dt} = U \exp((t - t_0)U); \tag 4$

then from (3) and (4),

$\dot X = \dfrac{d \exp((t - t_0)U)}{dt} X(t_0) = U \exp((t - t_0)U) X(t_0) = UX, \tag 5$

which validates the assertion that (3) is the solution to (2); at $t = t_0$ we have

$\exp((t_0 - t_0)U)X(t_0) = \exp(0) X(t_0) = IX(t_0) = X(t_0), \tag 6$

showing that our solution is consistent with the initial conditions on $X(t)$.

(4)-(6) demonstrate that our proposed solution (3) in fact *works*, but offer little insight as to how one might arrive at (3) other than some intelligent guesswork.  We may, however, *derive* (3) from (2) as follows:  differentiating (2) we find

$\ddot X = U \dot X = U(UX) = U^2 X; \tag 7$

$\dddot X = U^2 \dot X = U^2 UX = U^3X; \tag 8$

if we assume that, for some positive integer $k$,

$X^{(k)} = \dfrac{d^k X}{dt^k} = U^k X, \tag 9$

then, differentiating,

$X^{(k + 1)} = U^k \dot X = U^k UX = U^{k + 1} X, \tag{10}$

which inductively shows that (9) holds for all integers $n \ge 0$; if we now construct the power series expansion of $X(t)$ about $t = t_0$ we find

$X(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{X^{(n)}(t_0)(t - t_0)^n}{n!} = \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{U^n X(t_0)(t - t_0)^n}{n!}$
$= \left ( \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty \dfrac{U^n (t - t_0)^n}{n!} \right ) X(t_0) = \exp((t - t_0)U)X(t_0). \tag{11}$

in (7)-(11) we have presented a *derivation* of the solution (3), which to my mind is an advance on the mere *verification* presented in (4)-(6).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it can be solved column-wise, and in analogy to the scalar form of this differential equation.
The solution is 
$$X(t)=\exp\left(U t\right) X(0)$$
where $X(0)$ is the initial condition (matrix) and 
$$\exp(Ut)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(Ut)^n}{n!}$$ is the matrix exponential, which can be computed explicitly if eigenvectors and eigenvalues are known.
Let $U=W \Lambda V^T$ with diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ and left and right eigenvector matrices $V$ and $W$. Then,
$$\exp(Ut)=W \exp(\Lambda t) V^T$$
where
$$\Lambda = \textrm{diag}(\lambda_1 ,\ldots,\lambda_N )$$
is the diagonal matrix of the $N$ eigenvalues of $U$
$$\exp(\Lambda t) = \textrm{diag}(\exp(\lambda_1 t),\ldots,\exp(\lambda_N t))$$
If you assume the functions $a(t)$, $b(t)$ etc. to be scalars, you have $N=2$ and can compute the eigenvalues from the trace and determinant of $U$, $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=U_{11}+U_{22}$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=U_{11}U_{22}-U_{21}U_{12}$.